# (Binary) Summing the elements of a list

Tags: python

I need to sum the elements of a list, containing all zeros or ones, so that the result is 1 if there is a 1 in the list, but 0 otherwise.

```
def binary_search(l, low=0,high=-1):
    if not l: return -1
    if(high == -1): high = len(l)-1
    if low == high:
        if l[low] == 1: return low
        else: return -1
    mid = (low + high)//2
    upper = [l[mid:high]]
    lower = [l[0:mid-1]]
    u = sum(int(x) for x in upper)
    lo = sum(int(x) for x in lower)
    if u == 1: return binary_search(upper, mid, high)
    elif lo == 1: return binary_search(lower, low, mid-1)
    return -1

 l = [0 for x in range(255)]
 l[123] = 1
 binary_search(l)
```

The code I'm using to test

```
u = sum(int(x) for x in upper)
```

works fine in the interpreter, but gives me the error

TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

I've just started to use python, and can't figure out what's going wrong (the version I've written in c++ doesn't work either).

Does anyone have any pointers?

Also, how would I do the sum so that it is a binary xor, not simply decimal addition?

Comment: Where is `x` defined?

Comment: Do you just need the [`any` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any)?

Comment: @BrendanLong yes, it turned out that worked. First afternoon with Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to sum the elements of a list, containing all zeros or ones, so that the result is 1 if there is a 1 in the list, but 0 otherwise.

No need to sum the whole list; you can stop at the first 1.  Simply use `any()`. It will return `True` if there is at least one truthy value in the container and `False` otherwise, and it short-circuits (i.e. if a truthy value is found early in the list, it doesn't scan the rest). Conveniently, 1 is truthy and 0 is not.

`True` and `False` work as 1 and 0 in an arithmetic context (Booleans are a subclass of integers), but if you want specifically 1 and 0, just wrap `any()` in `int()`.

Answer (score 4):

You don't actually want a sum; you want to know whether `upper` or `lower` contains a `1` value. Just take advantage of Python's basic container-type syntax:

```
if 1 in upper:
    # etc
if 1 in lower:
    # etc
```

---

The reason you're getting the error, by the way, is because you're wrapping `upper` and `lower` with an extra nested list when you're trying to split `l` (rename this variable, by the way!!). You just want to split it like this:

```
upper = the_list[mid:high]
lower = the_list[:mid-1]
```

---

Finally, it's worth noting that your logic is pretty weird. This is not a binary search in the classic sense of the term. It looks like you're implementing "find the index of the first occurrence of `1` in this list". Even ignoring the fact that there's a built-in function to do this already, you would be much better served by just iterating through the whole list until you find a `1`. Right now, you've got `O(nlogn)` time complexity (plus a bunch of extra one-off loops), which is pretty silly considering the output can be replicated in `O(n)` time by:

```
def first_one(the_list):
    for i in range(len(the_list)):
        if the_list[i] == 1:
            return i
    return -1
```

Or of course even more simply by using the built-in function `index`:

```
def first_one(the_list):
    try:
        return the_list.index(1)
    except ValueError:
        return -1
```

Answer (score 3):

> I need to sum the elements of a list, containing all zeros or ones, so that the result is 1 if there is a 1 in the list, but 0 otherwise.

What's wrong with

```
int(1 in l)
```

Answer (score 2):

Stop making nested lists.

```
upper = l[mid:high]
lower = l[0:mid-1]
```

Comment: Thank you! I've only started using python this afternoon!